# checked conversion function for C++20

Tags: c++, template, c++20, casting

Similar to [C++ int_cast<> function for checked casts?](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/5515/7960), but C++20, and with target type deduced from context.

The goal is to implement a runtime check that the value being converted can be represented in the target type, and throw an exception if it can't.

This basically works for my use case, but I wonder if there's anything obvious I've missed.

Use as

```
std::uint32_t x = 0x40000000;
std::int32_t y = checked_cast(x);    // works
std::uint16_t z = checked_cast(x);   // throws
```

Code:

```
#pragma once

#include <stdexcept>
#include <utility>

class bad_checked_cast : public std::logic_error
{
public:
    bad_checked_cast() : std::logic_error("Bad checked_cast") { }
};

template<typename From>
struct checked_cast_result_proxy
{
    template<typename To>
    operator To() const
    {
        if(std::in_range<To>(value))
            return static_cast<To>(value);
        else
            throw bad_checked_cast();
    }

    From value;
};

template<typename From>
auto checked_cast(From value) -> checked_cast_result_proxy<From>
{
    return checked_cast_result_proxy<From> { value };
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There's an argument (no pun intended!) that it's not an error in the program logic for the value to be out of the convertible range.  I would suggest using `std::domain_error` as the base of `bad_checked_cast`.

---

We should constrain the template to reject types that `std::in_range()` doesn't accept:

```
#include <concepts>
⋮
template<typename From>
    requires std::integral<From>
struct checked_cast_result_proxy
⋮
    template<typename To>
       requires std::integral<To>
    operator To() const
```

`std::in_range` [cannot be used with](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/in_range#Notes)

> enums (including `std::byte`), `char`, `char8_t`, `char16_t`, `char32_t`, wchar_t and `bool`.

That's harder to enforce, as there isn't a concept that expresses that restriction (and the library I'm using allows invocation, but than fails at a `static_assert`).

---

I found it useful to have a plain function interface to collapse the proxy object, for when there isn't a specific enough context to do so (e.g. passing into another template function that requires an arithmetic type):

```
template<typename To, typename From>
    requires std::integral<From> && std::integral<To>
static To checked_cast_to(From from) { return checked_cast(from); }
```

That enabled me to test throwing with this:

```
TEST(CheckedCast, success)
{
    const std::uint32_t x = 0x40000000;
    std::int32_t y = checked_cast(x);
    EXPECT_EQ(x, y);
}

TEST(CheckedCast, fail)
{
    const std::uint32_t x = 0x40000000;
    EXPECT_THROW(checked_cast_to<std::uint16_t>(x), std::exception);
}
```

---

You could consider generalising to make it work with other (non-integer) arithmetic types (e.g. floating and complex numbers).  That might be a lot of work that's not useful for you, though.

Comment: Allowing the caller to manually specify the target-type is a good idea. But using a  different name for that is so inconvenient.